# Add [type] to fillable property to allow mass assignment error when inserting classname to table

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to insert a classname ie. App\Models\CustomerImport into a table using the following code:

```
$import = Import::create([
            'type' => $type, \\evaluates to App\Models\CustomerImport
            'campaign_id' => session('activeCampaign'),
            'filename' => $filename,
            'original_filename' => $originalFilename,
            'extra_attributes' => $extraAttributes,
        ]);
```

I'm getting the error, `Add [type] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Models\CustomerImport].`

Does anyone have an idea why this could be happening?

*EDIT*
Just to clear the confusion, Import and CustomerImport are two different models. I'm trying to insert data into the import table using the Import model. One of the columns is type which is supposed to be a classname. The Import model is below

```
class Import extends Model
{
    use LogsActivity;
    use HasChildren;

    protected $fillable = [
        'campaign_id',
        'type',
        'filename',
        'original_filename',
        'rows_total_count',
        'rows_success_count',
        'rows_error_count',
        'processed_at',
        'failed_at',
        'pruned_at',
    ];

 
   
}
```

**SOLUTION**
I've finally figured out the problem. I'm adopting a team member's csv import code to my app. In the Import and CustomerImport he's used the [Parental](https://github.com/calebporzio/parental) package from Caleb Porzio, . This gives the ability to access a child's model from a parent and vice versa. To do so, the CustomerImport model extends the Import model however I didn't notice this and mine was extending the default model hence the error.

Comment: Can you share your model `Import` ?

Comment: The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) has infos on mass assignment. Just add `type` to the `$fillable` array

Comment: The error message told you : to add `type` column to **fillable** property on your `App\Models\CustomerImport` model

Comment: I've added a clarification. CustomerImport and Import are two different models. I'm trying to insert data into the import table using the Import model which has a fillable attribute of 'type'

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `type` to class fillable property in your model.

**App\Models\CustomerImport**

```
class CustomerImport extends Model {
...
public $fillable = ['type','campaign_id','filename','original_filename','extra_attributes'];
...
}
```

Or you can add `$guarded` property which lets all property to be fillable.

```
class CustomerImport extends Model {
...
protected $guarded = [];
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In eloquent ORM, $fillable attribute is an array containing all those fields of table which can be filled using mass-assignment.

Mass assignment refers to sending an array to the model to directly create a new record in Database.

```
class CustomerImport extends Model 
{
     protected $fillable = [
        'type',
        'campaign_id',
        'filename',
        'original_filename',
        'extra_attributes'
    ];   
}
```

That should be solve the problem.